# How to get a JSON array response from GCM

Tags: php, android

Can anyone help me to get a response as a JSON array from GCM?

Here is the incorrect response I am getting. Can anyone help me with it?

I am creating a cab booking app. I want to collect all driver data including locations and push it through GCM so I can get real-time locations of every driver.

Here is my error.

```
E/response: [{"id":"suraj854","0":"Suraj","1":"1234567890","2":"42.6640983","3":"56.9954983"}]
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":"suraj854","0":"Suraj","1":"1234567890","2":"42.6640983","3":"56.9954983"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at elegantswebapps.cabdriver.services.GCMPushReceiverService$override.onMessageReceived(GCMPushReceiverService.java:68)
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at elegantswebapps.cabdriver.services.GCMPushReceiverService$override.access$dispatch(GCMPushReceiverService.java)
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at elegantswebapps.cabdriver.services.GCMPushReceiverService.onMessageReceived(GCMPushReceiverService.java:0)
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzq(Unknown Source)
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzp(Unknown Source)
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-03 16:18:17.228 8262-8325/elegantswebapps.cabdriver W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is my code:

```
public function fetchall_user_online_drivers_() {
    $smt = $this->conn->prepare("select * from driver where active_status=1");
    $smt->execute();
    $userdata = array();
    $registration_ids = array();
    while ($users = $smt->fetch()) {
        //array_push($userdata,$users["username"],$users["first_name"],$users["longitude_current"],$users["latitude_current"]);
        array_push($registration_ids, $users['gcm_id_token']);
        array_push($userdata,array('id'=>$users["username"],$users["first_name"],$users["phone"],$users["longitude_current"],$users["latitude_current"]));
    }  

    $data = array("message" => json_encode($userdata));

    $this->realTimeAllDriverLocations($registration_ids, $data);
}

public function realTimeAllDriverLocations($gcm_id, $userdata) {
    //Creating a new array fileds and adding the msg array and registration token array here 
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids'    => $gcm_id,
        'data'                => $userdata
    );

    //Adding the api key in one more array header 
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key= AIzaSyAlVrqgGDDZVM1G9_qoyEl1OinRFto8WhY',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ); 

    //Using curl to perform http request 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    //Getting the result 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    //Decoding json from result 
    $res = json_decode($result);

    //Getting value from success 
    $flag = $res->success;

    //if success is 1 means message is sent \
}
```

And this is how I am parsing the JSON array:

```
//This method will be called on every new message received
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle bundle) {
    //Getting the message from the bundle
    if (!bundle.isEmpty()) {
        data = bundle;
        String message = bundle.getString("message");
        try {
            Log.e("response", bundle.getString("message"));
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(message);
            Object obj = jobj.get("");
            if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
                final JSONArray jarr = (JSONArray) obj;
                if (jarr.length() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
                        All_UserMapDetail person = new All_UserMapDetail();
                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("username")) {
                            person.setName(jsonObject.getString("username"));
                        }
                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("title")) {
                            person.setPhone(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                            Log.e("hgcghcghc",person.getName() );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    sendNotification(data.getString(FIRST_NAME_DRIVER_KEY));
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Can you write your response which you got from log?

Answer (score 1):

From your logcat response is [{"id":"suraj854","0":"Suraj","1":"1234567890","2":"42.6640983","3":"56.9954983"}]
Your format is wrong, update your php script.
update this line from php script **array_push($userdata,array('id'=>$users["username"],$users["first_name"],$users["phone"],$users["longitude_current"],$users["latitude_current"]));**

to 
**array_push($userdata,array('username'=>$users["username"],'firstname'=>$users["first_name"],'phone'=>$users["phone"],'longitude_current'=>$users["longitude_current"],'latitude_current'=>$users["latitude_current"]));**

change your keys according your requirement. Update in below json parsing.

update your parsing code as follows :

```
JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(message);

                if (jaar != null && jarr.length() > 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
                        All_UserMapDetail person = new All_UserMapDetail();
                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("username")) {
                            person.setName(jsonObject.getString("username"));
                        }
                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("title")) {
                            person.setPhone(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                            Log.e("hgcghcghc",person.getName() );

                        }




                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**

You are a JSONArray but you try to parse by JSONObject.

Change the line `JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(message);` by this

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONArray(message).getJSONObject(POSITION);
```

**Second**

Change you server side code to get proper response . You are calling key `username` , `title` which is not are not in your response .

Comment: @SurajKumar ,  Appreciate with Upvote if it is useful :).

Comment: sir here two answer helped how can i upvote both answer? sorry i am new to stack overflow

Comment: For upvote click the uppor sign beside my answer , http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up Read for more details .
You can up vote both answer if you think those are helpful .